# Работа с MessageBox

Tags: visual-basic

Доброго времени суток. Я в данный момент пишу диплом, и у меня возник вопрос - как перехватить системную ошибку? Т.е. например - я при сохранении в базу укажу повторяющийся Id - и мне выбьет ошибку. Так вот - как ее изменить? В смысле, текст ошибки изменить?
P.S. Ошибка может быть только по Id - больше ей не на что быть на данной форме.
Заранее спасибо
P.S.S. Или, может быть, подскажите какой-нибудь альтернативный вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Текст ошибки, если я правильно понял вопрос, Вы не измените, он запрограммирован в системе. Но можно сделать альтернативу, например, проверять, повторяются ли Id-ы , или нет, а затем вызывать собственное диалоговое окно или выполнять другие действия на Ваше усмотрение.